# React-router v0.13 in jsfiddles?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I was trying to update a [working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d2mnwqLj/3/) with [react-router 0.13.2](http://jsfiddle.net/d2mnwqLj/6/), but it throws

`Uncaught ReferenceError: ReactRouter is not defined`

and other jsfiddles seem to do this as well. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React Router 0.13.2 requires React 0.13.x, but your fiddle is still using `react-with-addons.min.js` 0.12.2. [Use this one instead](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-router/0.13.2/ReactRouter.min.js).

Comment: Ah, of course! It just didn't click yesteday... Thanks a bunch! For anyone else who didn't know, there's react base jsfiddle for forking: https://jsfiddle.net/reactjs/69z2wepo/